# Criar vetores de novos tipos em Julia

Tags: array, julia

Não consigo criar criar vetores de novos tipos em julia, eles não funcionam.

O programa de exemplo é este:

```
# Meu tipo customizado
struct Job
    id::Int64
    order::Int64
    time::Float64
end

#Aqui eu crio o vetor
v = Vector{Job}()

#crio jobs para inserir no vetor
j1 = Job(1,1,1.0)
j2 = Job(2,1,1.1)
j3 = Job(3,1,1.2)

#As linhas seguintes não funcionam
append!(v, j1)
append!(v, j2)
append!(v, j3)


v #Vetor ainda vazio
```

Eu testei a mesma lógica com inteiros no lugar de Jobs e simplesmente funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para inserir um elemento do tipo *struct* no vetor, você deve utilizar a macro [`push!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.push!):

```
push!(v, j1)
push!(v, j2)
push!(v, j3)
```

Ou, caso prefira inserir os três elementos em um comando só:

```
push!(v, j1, j2, j3)
```

Resultado:

```
julia> v
3-element Array{Job,1}:
 Job(1, 1, 1.0)
 Job(2, 1, 1.1)
 Job(3, 1, 1.2)
```

---

A macro [`append!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.append!) é utilizada para inserir um *array* de elementos:

```
append!(v, [j1, j2, j3])
```

Resultado (após inserir novamente os três elementos):

```
julia> v
6-element Array{Job,1}:
 Job(1, 1, 1.0)
 Job(2, 1, 1.1)
 Job(3, 1, 1.2)
 Job(1, 1, 1.0)
 Job(2, 1, 1.1)
 Job(3, 1, 1.2)
```